# Do ETW calls take ownership of string pointers?

Tags: c++, windows, etw

I have an ETW provider, but the Visual Studio debug CRT is reporting memory leaks in it. The calls to register an event create a wchar_t* on the heap:

```
    auto msg = convertToWchar(string); // calls new wchar_t[]
    EventWriteBegin (msg);
```

The EventWriteBegin() function is a macro into the Template_xyz() function that is generated by the ETW compiler:

```
ULONG
Template_xyz(
    _In_ REGHANDLE RegHandle,
    _In_ PCEVENT_DESCRIPTOR Descriptor,
    _In_opt_ PCWSTR  _Arg0)
{
#define ARGUMENT_COUNT_zdf 1

    EVENT_DATA_DESCRIPTOR EventData[ARGUMENT_COUNT_zdf];

    EventDataDescCreate(&EventData[0], 
                        (_Arg0 != NULL) ? _Arg0 : L"NULL",
                        (_Arg0 != NULL) ? (ULONG)((wcslen(_Arg0) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR)) : (ULONG)sizeof(L"NULL"));

    return EventWrite(RegHandle, Descriptor, ARGUMENT_COUNT_zdf, EventData);
}
```

**My question is: can I assume that after the PCWSTR argument has been passed to EventDataDescCreate and EventWrite() has been called, can free the string that I pass to it?**

The docs for [EventDataDescCreate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/evntprov/nf-evntprov-eventdatadesccreate) and [EventWrite()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/evntprov/nf-evntprov-eventwrite) don't mention the lifetime semantics for the arguments.

Comment: in general the windows api doesn't take ownership of any passed parameters unless explicitly stated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Windows does take ownership, it will tell you how it will free that memory. That's usually `GlobalFree` or `CoTaskMemFree`, never `delete[]`. That obviously means you need the corresponding allocator instead of `new wchar_t[]`. Here, no ownership is transferred, so `new[]/delete[]` is fine.

"Allocated on the heap" is confusing in this context, because it can be interpreted as `HeapAlloc`, the OS function, instead of `new[]`